# How to set custom headers in UrlWebViewSource property to load WebView in .Net MAUI

Tags: .net, webview, maui

I am working on a .Net MAUI project that has Login Page which Authenticates and gets a Token from web server. I am using WebView control to load Homepage of my web application by passing HomeUrl in Web view source property, but It's redirected to login page with in the WebView, to skip this redirection need to pass token as cookie within header along with Home Url.

I am passing HomeUrl in WebView Control source property, but along with Url,

Expecting: Need to pass cookies(token) in the headers to load HomePage within WebView which skips Authentication.

Comment: I have vague memory that this is not possible. I ended up passing the token in the URL as parameter and setting up the server to verify it from there. (What is really going to mess with your logic is the lack of mechanic to detect http errors. Unless you write a bunch of platform specific code of course).